# How to only copy and paste highlighted text in an electron app?

Tags: javascript, electron, copy-paste

I am having a lot of **trouble implementing copy and paste** in to my electron app. I have made a copy and paste window ui but have been looking for a way to implement the copy and paste feature (That only copies highlighted text). I have been at this for a ***LONG*** time and tried to use the clipboard API from electron themselves but that does not copy highlighted text only text that you have added youself. I also tryed to make a button that would just run thr CTRL + C command but i could not get it to work, So any help would be muchly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should  add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Without sufficient details, It's impossible to see what is the problem here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get selected text from your own app window, you can use the web API [`Window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) normally like you would do in any web application that runs in the browser

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379408/9698583)

```js
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```

If you want a context menu (on right-click), you can use Electron [`Menu`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menupopupoptions) APIs to build this context menu with a copy menu item or you can use an npm package that does this for you [`electron-context-menu`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-context-menu)

If you want to get any highlighted text form any application, you can use synthesize a `CTRL+C` click then get the text from the clipboard. I have created an npm package [`electron-selected-text`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-selected-text) that does this for you and it preservers the old text in the clipboard as well

Comment: Thanks thats was the issue. Your a life saver 